# Change target link based on visitor's country

Tags: redirect

I have website.com/sample-page with some text and a download button (external link like download.com/file)

I want to change the target link (download.com/file) if a user is from France. I dont want to redirect entire page/website, only this link.

I am using wordpress (if helps).
Some advices, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is very simple, you need to detect the user language, then go with if, elseif, else and call the header location when need or simple doing echo of link...

```
$find = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
$lang = substr($find,0,2);
if ($lang == "fr") {
  header("Location: download.com/file_fr");
  exit();
} elseif ($lang == "it") {
  header("Location: download.com/file_it");
  exit();
} elseif ($lang == "xx") {
  header("Location: download.com/file_xx");
  exit();
} else {
  header("Location: download.com/file");
  exit();
}
```

or using another trick...

```
$link = "";
$find = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
$lang = substr($find,0,2);
if ($lang == "fr") {
  $link = "download.com/file_fr";
} elseif ($lang == "it") {
  $link = "download.com/file_it";
} elseif ($lang == "xx") {
  $link = "download.com/file_xx";
} else {
  $link = "download.com/file";
}
echo "<a href=\"$link\" target=\"_blank\">$link</a>";
```

Let's me know if my answer is what you want :)

Comment: Thanks Alessandro. Where should I use this code? In wp post, single, etc?

Comment: I improved my answer :)

Comment: Yes, I did it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you solved can you mark my answer as the solution? Thanks! :)

Comment: Simple click on my answer and so my answer will be marked green and marked as solution for all people :)